# Paginating MySQL Results with User Values from HTML Form

Tags: php, html, mysql, pagination

I'm not great with PHP, but I've got my project working pretty much as expected. My last piece is getting pagination to work correctly. By correctly, I mean retaining the submitted form values past page 1. I looked into Sessions and it seems like overkill as I'm already passing the results with `GET`.

Again, the pagination itself works, it just doesn't retain the form values. As I'm working with the query on the same page, I figured I could use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, but for some reason when this is in the `href` of the pagination, it either breaks the page and nothing is displayed, or generates a URL that doesn't resolve correctly—
`myurl.com/$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']?p=2—`as opposed to actually having values from `GET`.

Thoughts on this? I think I'm probably missing a character or brackets or something (again, PHP isn't my forte).

Thanks for any help!

```
function pagination($page,$num_page)
{
  echo'<ul style="list-style-type:none;">';
  for($i=1;$i<=$num_page;$i++)
  {
     if($i==$page)
{
 echo'<li style="float:left;padding:5px;">'.$i.'</li>';
}
else
{
 echo('<li style="float:left;padding:5px;"><a href="$_SERVER[\'REQUEST_URI\']?p='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>');
}
  }
  echo'</ul>';
}
if($num_page>1)
{
 pagination($page,$num_page);
}
```

Comment: `'<li style="float:left;padding:5px;"><a href="$_SERVER[\'REQUEST_URI\']?p='` < that won't work - `$vars` aren't converted to their values in `'` denoted strings : http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php - if you need to interpolate the values you need to use `"` denoted strings

Comment: Thanks @CD001! That did the trick. Should've asked here sooner, I've been struggling with it for a few hours now and obviously still haven't RTFM enough.